# KableExtra conditionally formatting specific rows on a column

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have just learnt KableExtra and know to how to use conditionally formating the entire column using mutate() as explained in the doc using mutate such as:

```
mutate(
   mpg = cell_spec(mpg, background = ifelse(mpg > 20, "red", "blue"))
)
```

But what I don't know is, how to change background colours of only certain rows in each column whilst all rows are being displayed.

For example, my data:

```
df <- data.frame( region1 = c("A", sample(1:5,3)),
                  region2 = c("B", sample(1:5,3)),
                  region3 = c("C", sample(1:5,3)),
                  region4 = c("A", sample(1:5,3)) )
```

Now I want to format only second and third row. I dont want to change the color background of first and last row. These second and third row should be 'red' when above 1, or yellow when equal to 1 or green when below 1.

Some one could help me this?

Comment: Will only the first row be letters and all other rows be numeric?

Comment: I needed to display a single table where few rows are strings and rest are numbers. I had to format numers in the different columns. I dont know how to handle dataframe with mixed type. Should I keep them serperately? If so how will I display them as a single table..:-(

Comment: I try to adhere to the tidy data format (see this [PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) for Hadley Wickham's paper on the subject) – in short, rows are observations, while columns are variables – so I would keep letters and numbers together if they refer to the same variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that ignores the first and last rows and colours according to value, like you say, but ignores letters.

First, I load the libraries.

```
# Load libraries
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

Next, I create a dummy data frame.

```
# Create data frame   
df <- data.frame( region1 = c(sample(c(-5:5, letters[1:5]), 10, replace = TRUE)),
                  region2 = c(sample(c(-5:5, letters[1:5]), 10, replace = TRUE)),
                  region3 = c(sample(c(-5:5, letters[1:5]), 10, replace = TRUE)),
                  region4 = c(sample(c(-5:5, letters[1:5]), 10, replace = TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Here, I define the function for formatting cells. I ignore the first and last rows and check if the character is a letter or number, then colour accordingly.

```
foo <- function(x, n, nmax){
  cell_spec(x, background = ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x)), "white",
                                   ifelse(n == nmax | n == 1, "white",
                                          ifelse(x > 1, "red",
                                                 ifelse(x < 1, "green", "yellow")))))
}
```

Finally, I apply the function.

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(foo(., n = row_number(), nmax = n()))) %>% 
  kable(escape = FALSE) %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: It is just fabulous. I have learnt and extended as per your help. Thanks a lot for saving my time. I was about to give up. Somebody told coding is poetry. But I see that in your function usage! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good design for a dataframe:  columns need to be all one type, so your numbers will be coerced to character.

Nevertheless, you can do what you ask for as follows.

```
fixcol <- function(col) {
  x <- as.numeric(col[2:3])
  x <- cell_spec(x, background = ifelse(x > 1, "red", ifelse(x == 1, "yellow", "green")))
  col[2:3] <- x
  col
}

df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, fixcol))
kable(df, escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I am getting an error : Error in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 2:3, value = NULL) : replacement has length zero. am  I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You could print `col` in the `fixcol` function.  If it has fewer than 3 entries, you'd get a message like that, because `x` would end up too short.

Comment: I increased the rows...now it turns...NA