# Table Spotlighting - change text colour based on value on multiple columns

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I would like to replicate the following table that in tableau is called [*Spotlighting*](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_ex2spotlighting.htm)

[image]

In my case I would like to replicate it with the following base that gives me color to the maximum value per row that are the questions I have an idea to do it with `cell_spec()` from the `kableExtra` package

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)


Name<-c("question1",  "question",  "question3",  "question4", 
        "question5",  "question6",  "question7",  "question8", 
        "question9",  "question10")
A<-c(0, 3 ,0 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
B<-c(5, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1)
C<-c(3, 0, 2 ,2 ,0 ,1, 0 ,1 ,0 ,2)
D<-c(4, 1, 3 ,2 ,0 ,5, 0 ,1 ,3 ,2)

tab<-data.frame("Name"=Name,"A"=A,"B"=B,"C"=C,"D"=D)

tab%>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_paper("striped",full_width = F)
```

[image]

Remember that I want to get a table with a similar format only that now I will only show the largest number in the table

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/53341155/680068 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/68048594/680068

Comment: @zx8754 In those cases I only refer to one row, in my case I want it to apply to all of them at the same time to replicate it in much larger tables

Comment: Do we want to highlight the largest value per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the numeric columns and add a colour based on the value (change the *ifelse* statement as needed):

```
tab %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, 
            function(i){
              cell_spec(i, color = ifelse(i > 1, "green", "red"))}) %>% 
  kbl(escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = FALSE)
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

To do the same per row, we can transpose, then as above loop through columns and change the colour based on value, then transpose it back again:

```
# transpose, get colour, transpose
tmp <- data.frame(t(
  data.frame(t(tab[ -1 ])) %>% 
  mutate_all(function(i) cell_spec(i, color = ifelse(i == max(i), "green", "red")))
  ), row.names = NULL)

# keep 1st name column, add other formatted columns, and kable
cbind(tab[ 1 ], tmp) %>%
  kbl(escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer for highlighting positive values.  As a follow on, is it possible to change the "1" in `ifelse(i > 1, ...` to be flexible, e.g. the maximum of the row or values greater than 2 SD above the mean for that row?  Thank you.

Comment: @TechCommodities Yes, we can apply any function within "function", but it would be based on per column.

Comment: @TechCommodities see edit, now it highlights per row that matches row max value.

Comment: Good solution - Transpose, action the columns, transpose